# SELECT with INNER JOIN slow for some timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I have a strange problem with Select statement. It's returning a 10-min average values from 3 tables between given timestamps. The strange part is that it's working fast (0.1s) for some date ranges and slow (60-250s or `ORA-65114: space usage in container is too high`) for others. I noticed that most of the times it doesn't work with recent dates (today, yesterday). I'm querying a daily reports - `:TIMEFROM: 2022-08-16T22:00:00.000Z, :TIMETO: 2022-08-17T21:59:59.999Z`. For these values it won't work mostly but days before that it will no problem. Also when I remove WHERE clause, it'll be fast as well. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

TIME.VALUEs are timestamp type

Here is an explain plan:

[image]

And the code:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE, 'MI') - MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE), 10) / (24 * 60) AS TIME_VALUE,
                AVG(SOCOMEC_1.METER_POWER) AS METER_POWER,
                AVG(HOTEL1_FRONIUS_WSCHOD.INVERTER_POWER) AS FRONIUS_WSCHOD,
                AVG(HOTEL1_FRONIUS_ZACHOD.INVERTER_POWER) AS FRONIUS_ZACHOD
                FROM SOCOMEC_1
                INNER JOIN HOTEL1_FRONIUS_WSCHOD ON
                SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE = HOTEL1_FRONIUS_WSCHOD.TIME_VALUE 
                INNER JOIN HOTEL1_FRONIUS_ZACHOD ON
                SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE = HOTEL1_FRONIUS_ZACHOD.TIME_VALUE
                WHERE SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE > TO_TIMESTAMP(:TIMEFROM, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"') AND SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE < TO_TIMESTAMP(:TIMETO, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"')
                GROUP BY TRUNC(SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE, 'MI') - mod(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE), 10) / (24 * 60)
                ORDER BY TRUNC(SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE, 'MI') - mod(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM SOCOMEC_1.TIME_VALUE), 10) / (24 * 60) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a function and a virtual column. Could be like this:

```
FUNCTION MakeInterval(ts IN TIMESTAMP, roundInterval IN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND) RETURN TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC IS
    denom INTEGER;
BEGIN
    IF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' HOUR THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(HOUR FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(24, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts) + TRUNC(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' HOUR;
    ELSIF roundInterval >= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE THEN
        denom := EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM roundInterval);
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'hh') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE;
    ELSE
        denom := EXTRACT(SECOND FROM roundInterval);                
        IF MOD(60, denom) <> 0 THEN
            RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
        END IF;
        RETURN TRUNC(ts, 'mi') + TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM ts) / denom) * denom * INTERVAL '1' SECOND;
    END IF;
END MakeInterval;


ALTER TABLE SOCOMEC_1 ADD (INTERVAL_10_MINS TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
   MakeInterval(TIME_VALUE, INTERVAL '10' MINUTE)
) virtual);
CREATE INDEX INTERVAL_10_MINS_IDX ON SOCOMEC_1.INTERVAL_10_MINS (INTERVAL_10_MINS);

SELECT SOCOMEC_1.INTERVAL_10_MINS AS TIME_VALUE, ...
FROM SOCOMEC_1 
   ...
GROUP SOCOMEC_1.INTERVAL_10_MINS
ORDER BY SOCOMEC_1.INTERVAL_10_MINS
```

The function provides generic intervals. Of course, you can hard-code 10 Minutes interval in column definition directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't help though. Getting "ORA-65114: space usage in container is too high"

Comment: Then you may allocate more space to the container.

Comment: For the cases where it fails with a space error, the execution plan may be using temp space and the database seems to not have enough space. You can try after scaling up the storage.